# Ajax call with ONLY javascript (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I'm trying to do an ajax call with POST method, but the PHP only return an empty array. What am i doing wrong?

JAVASCRIPT

```
// ajax call

function makeRequest(){

    var http_request = false;
    // example data
    var fileObjectInfo = 'bla';
    var url = 'archivo.php';

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (http_request.overrideMimeType) {
            http_request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
        }
    }else if(window.ActiveXObject){
        try{
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }catch(e){
            try{
                http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }catch(e){}
        }
    }

    if (!http_request) {
        console.log('Falla :( No es posible crear una instancia XMLHTTP');
        return false;
    }


    http_request.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
    http_request.open('POST', url, true);
    http_request.send(fileObjectInfo);


    function alertContents(){

        if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
            if (http_request.status == 200) {

                console.log(http_request.responseText);

            } else {
                console.log('Hubo problemas con la petición.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My php only do: `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` (i tried with request too), but always return an emty array. (so the call works but javascrip doesn't send the information, no?)

I get examples code from internet but never works the ajax call with POST method and i don't know why.

thank you in advance for all the help they can lend.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending POST data with a XMLHttpRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-with-a-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: really i try to send a JavasCript Object, but when it doesn't work i tried with a string

Comment: I read this tutorial to do my script: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax

Answer (score 0):

If You request post method you must be pass header data with request like

```
http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", fileObjectInfo.length);
http_request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
```

put this data before http_request.send(fileObjectInfo);

I hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for the help but it doesn't works, it still return an empty array, no changes.

Comment: Please refer the basic example code http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_post2 it will help you

Comment: In the example i don't understand why they use the post method and next send the information using get "xhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");"

Comment: In simple javascript ajax post method always pass the query string in send function if you use get in ajax query string pass after url

Comment: post and get method rule in ajax is if you want to get data from server you can use get method if you submit more data to server you can user post method this is standardized rule

Comment: and hoy i send a object, y tried with '?data='+Object  but in php only return data ={}

Comment: Please check php file i think problem in your php file

Comment: How can i get a problem with print_r($_REQUEST)? (i prove $_POST, var_dump), What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To send a POST request you need a form data object containing key value pairs for PHP to interpret post values

```
var fileObjectInfo = new FormData();
fileObjectInfo.append("key", "value");
fileObjectInfo.append("name", "prince");

// ajax code
http_request.send(fileObjectInfo);
```

In PHP then do this

```
echo $_POST["key"];
echo $_POST["name"];
```

Be sure to check if the post params exist using isset()